# Reading child objects using xmltree in python

Tags: python

XML body (response.content)

```
<MediaPropertiesLayout>
    <header>
        <entry>
            <displayName>Q</displayName>
            <mediaProperty>callVariable1</mediaProperty>
            <showInPopOver>false</showInPopOver>
        </entry>
    </header>
    <column>
        <entry>
            <displayName>CallType</displayName>
            <mediaProperty>callVariable1</mediaProperty>
            <showInPopOver>true</showInPopOver>
        </entry>
    </column>
    <column>
        <entry>
            <displayName>QueueName</displayName>
            <mediaProperty>callVariable2</mediaProperty>
            <showInPopOver>true</showInPopOver>
        </entry>
    </column>
    <uri>/finesse/api/MediaPropertiesLayout/2</uri>
    <name>CallTest</name>
    <description>Test Variable</description>
    <type>CUSTOM</type>
</MediaPropertiesLayout>
```

I am trying to read the child objects (./column/entry/) from the above boxy which is a GET response from a server.

O/p i need is

```
CallType
callVariable1
true
Left
callVariable2
false

<Space>

QueueName
callVariable2
true
Right
callVariable4
false
```

However i am getting the desired o/p with no space. Reason for the space is so i can populate the 2nd child in a different column in the excel workbook.

```
CallType
callVariable1
true
Left
callVariable2
false
QueueName
callVariable2
true
Right
callVariable4
false
```

```
subroot= ET.fromstring(response.content)

for subchild in subroot.findall('./column/entry/'):
    print(subchild.text)
```

Thanks
Senthil

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *findall()*, one way to achieve this would be by using xml.etree *iter()* function https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter

*iter()* will help you get each individual `<entry>` sub child as a separate object. Then you can iterate through these objects and put a new line(or space as you are calling it in your case) after each object. The code would look something like this:

```
subroot = ET.fromstring(response_content) # read from a string variable
for  entry in subroot.iter('column'):
    [print(entry[0][i].text) for i in range(len(entry[0]))]
    print("\n") # any special character you want to print after each object
```

Expected output with above code:

```
CallType
callVariable1
true


QueueName
callVariable2
true
```

**Assumption:** Each `<entry>` sub child have equal number of sub children